Using typescript SDK in Javascript
I would like to try use SDK from Antropic so I tried to follow this guide, but stuck with this error:
TypeError: 'text/html' is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.

My guess is that I am not properly handling typescript SDK from JS, but I would appreciated any hint how to move forward.
HTML code:
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="js/ai.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

JS code:
import Anthropic from '/@anthropic-ai/sdk';

const anthropic = new Anthropic({
  apiKey: process.env['ANTHROPIC_API_KEY'], // This is the default and can be omitted
});

async function main() {
  const message = await anthropic.messages.create({
    max_tokens: 1024,
    messages: [{ role: 'user', content: 'Hello, Claude' }],
    model: 'claude-3-opus-20240229',
  });

  console.log(message.content);
}
main();

EDIT: I am using MAMP to simulate the server for this proof of concept study.

do you really want to expose your ANTHROPIC_API_KEY value to your site visitors?

No I don't @IT goldman, this is just for internal proof of concept study. And code I copy pasted form tutorial.

it is different accessing API from browser or from server, because the browser poses some limits to prevent abuses. when the documentation says client it means consumers of the API  and not necessarily the browser

Oh, right, I forgot to write I am using MAMP to simulate the server. I will edit question. Thank you for reminder @ITgoldman
